# Using AngularJS Scope Variable in another scope Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a Problem with the AngularJS Scope. I want to use a Variable of it, which contains an Object. In the Object I want one index which is saved in another scope Variable.
So I want something like that:

```
{{graphdata.nodes._data.{{selectedElements.nodes[0]}} }}
```

`graphdata.nodes._data` is the Object, and the index I want is saved in `selectedElements.nodes[0]`. Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot and shouldn't interpolate twice. just write:

```
{{graphdata.nodes._data[selectedElements.nodes[0]]}}
```